# how to set source parameter for bitmap image in mxml using action script

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I am very new to actionscript. I want to access already existing BitmapImage in mxml so as to change its source The Bitmap Image already exists im mxml with its id. I dont hav e to create it dynamically only its source is to be set.
I have seen some examples but they add image itself dynamically I dont want that.
Action Script3 is to be used.

here is the code:
Kindly suggest.

```
<fx:Script>
//code to set image source to url1(a string)
</fx:Script>

<s:Graphic>    
    <s:BitmapImage 
        id="ini_image"
        source="@Embed('C:/horizontal_red.png')" 
        width="640" 
        height="480" 
        fillMode="scale"
        includeIn="ready"
             />
</s:Graphic>
```

I tried it like this :

```
var ini_image:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
ini_image.source = url;
```

But it gives error in namespace might be because ii is creating a new object of same type with same name. Which is not allowed.
Please correctify me if I am wrong and suggest corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have more than one state in your application, so you have to take care if the ready state was or not initialized before setting the BitmapImage source. Hope the following code example will solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               currentState="other">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="ready"/>
        <s:State name="other"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        private function onButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            currentState = 'ready';

            ini_image.source = 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200';
        }
        ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:Graphic>
        <s:BitmapImage
                id="ini_image"
                source="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"
                width="640"
                height="480"
                fillMode="scale"
                includeIn="ready"
                />
    </s:Graphic>


    <s:Button click="onButtonClick(event)"/>

</s:Application>
```

You can also include image in both states and use different image source.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               currentState="other">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="ready"/>
        <s:State name="other"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Graphic>
        <s:BitmapImage
                id="ini_image"
                source.other="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"
                source.ready="http://lorempixel.com/200/200"
                width="640"
                height="480"
                fillMode="scale"/>
    </s:Graphic>

    <s:Button click="onToggleStates(event)"/>

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        private function onToggleStates(event:MouseEvent):void {
            currentState = currentState == 'other' ? 'ready' : 'other';
        }
        ]]></fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It works on button click i dont have any button in view I have to just show that image as soon as that swf is loaded. For this when I try to access the same format ini_image.source as only in script it doesnt work as gives error "Access of undefined property ini_image". Can u suggest some method to make it work

Comment: You don't have to specify any 'ready' states for this. Simply set the image source it will be displayed on application creation complete. Use this code: <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
            <s:BitmapImage source="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
    </s:Application>

Comment: Yeah it would work but I had to load the url I get dynamically as string.I used the same syntax ini_image.source= "url1" but it was not working as I gave file address of a file on my system. It can be set only via mxml dynamically it needs file from server. As soon as url was changed to server file it worked!!